# Hadoop data cross calculation

Tags: hadoop

I have a huge file, which contains a list of numbers, for example A0, A1, ..., An. I want to calculate values for all combinations of Ai and Aj using a complex operation (op). So I want the values

op(A1, A2), op(A1, A3), ....., op(An, An-2), op(An, An-1)

or event more op(A1, A2, A3), op(A1, A2, A4), ....

My questions is the huge file contains all numbers are divided into segments on nodes. How can I get number Ai & Aj which are not on the same node?

thanks

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11083357/4815083

Comment: This really answers my question, but in my case there is no filter at all. And although I use Ai in my question. in fact every Ai is a vector with 4000+ elements. So if I use this method, the data transfer maybe huge, that's what I'm worry about.